# Gerar gráficos de merge e branches no GIT?

Tags: git, documentação

Gostaria de uma ferramenta para documentar as minhas atividades no GIT, que gerasse um fluxograma como esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que ferramenta geraria uma documentação de merges, branches, tags, releasses no GIT, ou seja, documentar minha atividade ?

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo o gitk. Ele é livre e capaz de coisas como essa:

[image: Exemplo do Gitk]